# Where is the metadata?

Tags: file, operating-system, metadata

So i was just playing with files like opening with hex editor and doing some stuff. and i found one thing...
 i can access the data stored in a file but where are the metadata like file property, time stamps and other things are stored?

it's definitely not stored inside the file but where it is? is it stored somewhere in HardDrive filesystem or anywhere else? i also noticed that the NTFS file system can also store permissions like i can use dos command cacls (or icacls) on NTFS filesystem but it does not support filesystems like FAT32.
 and if it is on the harddrive then we can change the metadata (file properties hidden,archive etc) using linux (am i right)?

please can someone explain or tell me where i can find the right information about this topic.

Comment: how is this question related to C++?

Comment: You've not mentioned anything about C++ in that question. Tell us more what you've done so far in C++ to approach the solution. otherwise, this looks a bit off-topic.

Comment: @johndoe I edited the tags to be more relevant to what you're asking. Also, which operating in particular are you asking about? Windows and Linux file metadata are most likely stored in separate places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metadata stored separately from file data. Usually in structures called `inode`, but its depends on filesystem used.  On Linux, you work with meta data through API provided through function `chmod`(2), `chown`(2) etc. Number in parentheses is section number, you read about these with man command:  `man -s2 chown`. For command-line, linux have commands with similar names (chmod, chown, touch, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the filesystem itself allocates additional space for storing metadata on the disk.
 All operating systems give you an API that allows changing the metadata of files (timestamps, attributes, name, etc.).

and  you can by opening the appropriate device file for a partition or hard disk (e.g. "\.\C:") and reading/writing to it. When you know the details of the file system, you can figure out the metadata location(s) for a specific file on the disk.